# Injecting factory to controller doesn't work in angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I'm going crazy with this one.

I have 3 files:
app.js, 
app.services.provider.js, 
admin.js

In app.js I define my module:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider 
        .when("/admin", {
            templateUrl : "Admin.htm",
            controller: "AdminController"
        }).otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'} ) ;
    })

})();
```

Now in app.services.provider.js I define a factory:

```
(function() {

 angular.module("myApp").factory('appServicesProvider',function($scope, $http ) {
      function someFunction(){

      }

      return{someFunction:someFunction}

    });

})();
```

And in admin.js I have my controller:

```
(function() {

angular.module("myApp")
.controller("AdminController",function($scope, $http, appServicesProvider) {

});

})();
```

Now I believe I include the JS in the right order in my index.html:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.services.provider.js"></script>
<script src="js/admin.js"></script>
```

Yet when I try to run the code I get the exception:

```
angular.min.js:122 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=<ng-view class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20appServicesProvide
```

And I can't seem to understand when goes wrong

I tried several things:

- I tried including the scripts in both `head` and at the end of `body` tag
- I tried removing the `(function() {})();`
- I tried referencing my module in a var, i.e `var app = angular.module(...)` and using the variable across the files
- I tried injecting the "AppServices" like this: 
    `angular.module("myApp")
      .controller("AdminController",["$scope","$http","appServicesProvider",function($scope, $http, appServicesProvider) {...`

And it still shows that damn error.

Anyone has an idea what could have went wrong?

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to inject `$scope` into your service. There is no `$scope` for services.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. Thank you very much for your help!